# Next avaliable number/ID in SQL Server when not an int and contains letter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

**Preface**

I am currently rewriting an application which has a pretty interesting way of doing some things. Those certain things they want done the same way and I don't have much control of the data or it's structure. Mainly because they want it to be backwards compatible with their old program along with other programs used throughout the company.

**Problem**

They use a public facing employee ID throughout the company. It is the letter E and 4 digits. It is stored in the database as `char(5)`. So an example ID is E1234. Assigning this ID is a manual process. The problem is it is starting to be hard to maintain. Periodically they take the last ID used and make a list of several hundred usable IDs. They then cross out the IDs as they are used. Wash, rinse, repeat. On paper they are about 2/3s burned through every ID. Database wise there is a lot of unused IDs and IDs that can be decommissioned and they realistically have 2/5th of the possible IDs used. Fortunately it is unlikely this company will ever have 9,999 active employees.

**Solution**

In the new program the above problem can go away if we can determine and assign an available ID for for them as they create a new employee. I have found a lot of solutions looking for the next usable number but they seem to cater only if you are using an `int` and not a `char(5)` with a letter. Is it possible to do what I want and if so how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order by a substring of your employeeID column, you'll be able to get the highest value.  From there, you can add 1.  Working sample:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (col1 CHAR(5));

INSERT INTO @tbl
        ( col1 )
VALUES  ( 'E0521' ),
( 'E1542' ),
( 'E1543' )

-- prove to yourself that the ordering is correct
SELECT *
FROM @tbl 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, 2, 4) AS INT) DESC

DECLARE @max INT;
--get the max value
SELECT @max = MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, 2, 4) AS INT))
FROM @tbl

-- increment the max value and put E back on the front
SELECT 'E' + cast (@max + 1 AS CHAR(4))
```

Comment: Close but won't work for me. If `E9999` is in use then it returns `E*` rather than checks for an unused ID between `E0001` and `E9999`.

Comment: With some tweaking I got this one to work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only viable solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   EmployeeID AS 'E' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `EmployeeID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `EmployeeID` will contain values like `E0001`, `E0002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Comment: Not the *only* viable solution, but the most sane.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this. As stated in the preface I can't change anything on the DB end including the column design/data.

Answer (score 0):

If on 2012+ I prefer to use a `SEQUENCE`:

```
create sequence dbo.EmployeeId
as tinyint
start with 0
increment by 1
no maxvalue
no cycle
cache 100;
```

**Usage:**

```
-- create demo table
if Object_Id(N'tempdb..#Employees') is null
begin;
    create table #Employees (
        EmployeeId char(5) not null primary key clustered (EmployeeId asc)
    );

    -- create some collisions
    insert into #Employees (EmployeeId)
    select a.*
    from (values
        (N'E0000')
      , (N'E0002')
      , (N'E1234')
    ) as a (EmployeeId);
end;

-- insert next id
declare @employeeId char(5) = 'E' + Right('0000' + Convert(varchar(4), next value for dbo.EmployeeId), 4);

while exists (
    select 1
    from #Employees as a with (rowlock)
    where a.EmployeeId = @employeeId
)
begin;
    set @employeeId = 'E' + Right('0000' + Convert(varchar(4), next value for dbo.EmployeeId), 4);
end;

if (Convert(int, Right(@employeeId, 4)) > 9999)
begin;
    throw 50000, N'All EmployeeIds are currently in use.', 1;
end;

insert into #Employees (EmployeeId)
select @employeeId as EmployeeId;

-- check results
select * from #Employees;
```

Assuming that you can create just the sequence object then this should do exactly what you need. It works by calling `next value for ...` on the sequence until it encounters a value that isn't already in use by the table.

If you're unable to rely on a `SEQUENCE` object then you can choose to use the following query to pull the next id value.

```
select @employeeId = 'E' + Convert(varchar(4), Min(Convert(int, Right(a.EmployeeId, 4))))
from #Employees as a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple. There are only 10000 possible IDs, so this is solveable through brute force:

- Fill in all 10K ids using blank biodata
- Blank out biodata for "defunct" rows (to allow their reuse)

Every time you need a new id:

```
select min(id) from employees
where firstname == '';
```

Then update the biodata for that id, thus making it ineligible for use as a new id:

```
update employees set
firstname = 'Fred'
-- etc
where id = $chosenId
and firstname == '' -- protection against concurrent first use
```

This approach requires absolutely no changes or additions to existing schema.

---

Note: I have chosen `firstname` as the "data semaphore", but you can chose whatever column *must* be not blank for an actual person.